# Clicking the same button but different action - c#

Tags: c#, button, click, focus

When i click on a button,text will appear in textbox1 but then i want it to change focus to another textbox(textbox2) and when i click the same button again,display the same text but in textbox2.

```
    private void btna_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = ("A");
        if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            textBox2.Focus();
        }
```

Comment: Use a boolean field to store and track in which "mode" the button is (or perhaps instead of using a boolean, better create an enum for that purpose)...

Comment: When you click the button your textbox will lose focus - so you can't use the focus to determine which textbox to interact with. Use a variable to keep track of the next textbox to interact with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to alternate between different TextBoxes in your click event to determine which one to update, you can track them in a private variable, and then just switch which one you're using based on the current value, for example:

```
private TextBox textBoxToUpdate = null;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Swap the textBoxToUpdate between textBox1 and textBox2 each time
    textBoxToUpdate = (textBoxToUpdate == textBox1) ? textBox2 : textBox1;

    textBoxToUpdate.Text = "A";
}
```

---

Another way to do this if you're updating multiple controls is to store them in a list and increment an integer that defines the index to the next item.

```
// holds the text boxes we want to rotate between
private List<TextBox> textBoxesToUpdate = new List<TextBox>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    // add some text boxes to our list
    textBoxesToUpdate.Add(textBox1);
    textBoxesToUpdate.Add(textBox2);
    textBoxesToUpdate.Add(textBox3);
    textBoxesToUpdate.Add(textBox4);
}

// stores the index of the next textBox to update
private int textBoxToUpdateIndex = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textBoxesToUpdate[textBoxToUpdateIndex].Text = "A";

    // increment the index but set it back to zero if it's equal to the count
    if(++textBoxToUpdateIndex == textBoxesToUpdate.Count) textBoxToUpdateIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup its good,but how to do it with 4 textboxes? (textbox1,textbox2,textbox3,textbox4)

Comment: Put them in a list, access them by index, and increment an integer to track the next index. I can post an example later

Comment: Ok i added a sample, but i did this from my phone so it's not completely tested...